# when updating records query doesn't return "No of rows affected"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have written a query which will check for a record existence, If condition is true, it will update else it will insert a new record.
The problem is while inserting, It returns `Query returned successfully: 1 rows affected, 200ms execution time.`

but when updating It returns "Query returned successfully: 0 rows affected, 190 ms execution time." but the value is updated correctly.

here is the sample script to create table

```
CREATE TABLE sample
(
  templateid integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('checktemplate_language_lookup_seq'::regclass),
  languageid integer NOT NULL,
  templatetitle character varying(100),
  disclaimer text,
  createdby integer NOT NULL,
  createdtimestamp timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT ('now'::text)::timestamp without time zone,
  updatedby integer,
  updatedtimestamp timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT sample_templateid_languageid UNIQUE (templateid, languageid)
)
```

To Insert new record in a table :

```
WITH new_values (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby,createdtimestamp,updatedby,updatedtimestamp)
    AS (
        VALUES (1, 1, 'LangTemplateTitle1', 'LangDisclaimer1', 1,current_timestamp,1,current_timestamp)
        ), upsert
    AS (
        UPDATE sample m
        SET templatetitle = nv.templatetitle, disclaimer = nv.disclaimer, updatedby = nv.updatedby, updatedTimeStamp = nv.updatedtimestamp
        FROM new_values nv
        WHERE m.templateId = nv.templateId AND m.languageId = nv.languageId RETURNING m.*
        )
    INSERT INTO sample (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby,createdtimestamp)
    SELECT templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby ,createdtimestamp
    FROM new_values
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM upsert up
            WHERE up.templateId = new_values.templateId AND up.languageId = new_values.languageId
            )
```

To update the same row with different values:(same query value updated)

```
WITH new_values (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby,createdtimestamp,updatedby,updatedtimestamp)
    AS (
        VALUES (1, 1, 'LangTemplateTitle2', 'LangDisclaimer2', 1,current_timestamp,1,current_timestamp)
        ), upsert
    AS (
        UPDATE sample m
        SET templatetitle = nv.templatetitle, disclaimer = nv.disclaimer, updatedby = nv.updatedby, updatedTimeStamp = nv.updatedtimestamp
        FROM new_values nv
        WHERE m.templateId = nv.templateId AND m.languageId = nv.languageId RETURNING m.*
        )
    INSERT INTO sample (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby,createdtimestamp)
    SELECT templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby ,createdtimestamp
    FROM new_values
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM upsert up
            WHERE up.templateId = new_values.templateId AND up.languageId = new_values.languageId
            )
```

How do i get "no of rows affected value" even I do updation with the same query

Comment: It returns the row count from your INSERT statement which is working even if there is no record to insert. So you got that message.

Comment: My question is that, when updating the same row It should return No of rows affected right ?

Comment: You need to change your query. You can only see the last statement's message. AND UPDATE is before the INSERT. You may use IF or something like that.

Comment: Actually, It will update when the record is exist only right, So It will not execute insert statement if record already there.

Comment: Your INSERT will work in any case. It just won't insert anything because its SELECT will return 0 rows. But, INSERT will work. And It will INSERT 0 records. Look at your query, there is no IF or something like that before your INSERT. Therefore it works.

Comment: For instance this query works "SELECT 1 WHERE 1 <> 1" And it returns 0 records. And If I write INSERT INTO with this SELECT, that INSERT also works and inserts 0 records.

Answer (score 1):

The default PG behaviour is to return only a message related to the final statement, which in this case is always the `INSERT` statement, even if the `UPDATE` actually does the work and the `INSERT` statement does nothing. If you want to customize the messages then you have to turn this statement into a PL/pgSQL function where you can `RAISE NOTICE` some message of your own design.

That said, if you are using **PG 9.5+**, you can use the `ON CONFLICT` clause of `INSERT` for a much cleaner statement:

```
INSERT INTO sample (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby, createdtimestamp)
VALUES (1, 1, 'LangTemplateTitle1', 'LangDisclaimer1', 1,current_timestamp)
ON CONFLICT (templateId, languageId) DO UPDATE
SET templatetitle = EXCLUDED.templatetitle, disclaimer = EXCLUDED.disclaimer,
    updatedby = EXCLUDED.createdby, updatedTimeStamp = EXCLUDED.createdtimestamp;
```

Note carefully the final two `SET` assignments: you specify a reference and a time for inserting, but when an update takes place these values become the update reference and time. `EXCLUDED` refers to the row whose values cause the conflict, in this case the values from the `VALUES` clause.

Even if you are on **PG9.4-** you can improve your query by using `RETURNING *` information rather than a costly `WHERE EXISTS`:

```
WITH nv (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, opBy, opTimestamp) AS (
    VALUES (1, 1, 'LangTemplateTitle2', 'LangDisclaimer2', 1, current_timestamp)
), upsert AS (
    UPDATE sample m
    SET templatetitle = nv.templatetitle, disclaimer = nv.disclaimer, updatedby = nv.opBy, updatedTimeStamp = nv.opTimestamp
    FROM nv
    WHERE m.templateId = nv.templateId AND m.languageId = nv.languageId
    RETURNING m.*
)
INSERT INTO sample (templateId, languageId, templatetitle, disclaimer, createdby, createdtimestamp)
SELECT nv.templateId, nv.languageId, nv.templatetitle, nv.disclaimer, nv.opBy, nv.opTimestamp
FROM nv, upsert
WHERE upsert.templateId IS NULL;
```

This exploits the fact that if the `UPDATE` does not take place, `RETURNING *` returns all nulls. Note also the use of `opBy` and `opTimestamp` to simplify the statement further.